# Cannot serve Cloned Git repository in my local machine

Tags: laravel, github

One of my friends have created a laravel app and he has made a repository in GitHub. But once I cloned it and run **php artisan serve** command it displays the following error.

```
 **Warning: require(C:\Users\j\Desktop\newsLankaPhp2-2\newsLankaPhp2-2\bootstrap/..
 /vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in   C:\Us
   ers\j\Desktop\newsLankaPhp2-2\newsLankaPhp2-2\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17**

  **Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\j\Desktop\newsLankaPhp
 2-2\newsLankaPhp2-2\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.; C:\xampp\
   php\PEAR') in
   C:\Users\j\Desktop\newsLankaPhp2-2\newsLankaPhp2-2\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17**
```

I am new to laravel and I need some help regarding this.

Comment: Try running `composer install` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: this solves the issue. but something else troubles me now. when I serve it using ** php artisan serve** command the following error occurs.  .env **Whoops, looks like something went wrong.**  And file is not cloned into my local working space

Comment: create the session folder and create the .env file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you clone a Laravel Repository, you have to make this Step: 
- Composer install 
- Copy .env.example to .env and set the good values inside .env